# backreference into strcapture regex

Tags: r

I have the following vector:

```
cpf <- "12345678910"
```

The following function works:

```
strcapture("(\\b.{3})(.{3})(.{3})(.{2}\\b)", cpf, 
       proto = list(n1 = character(), n2 = character(), n3 = character(), n4 = character()))

   n1  n2  n3 n4
1 123 456 789 10
```

But, when add the backreference `\\` does not work:

```
strcapture("(\\b.{3})\\1\\1(.{2}\\b)", cpf, 
       proto = list(n1 = character(), n2 = character(), n3 = character(), n4 = character()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a misunderstanding of what a `\1` backreference means.  When you include `\1` in your regex pattern, it is referring to whatever was captured in the first capture group.  So in the following input:

```
12345678910
```

The first capture group would be `123`.  As this is never repeated anywhere else subsequently in the input, `\1` will never match anything.  Consider the following example, which should work with the latest pattern:

```r
cpf <- "12312312310"
strcapture("\\b(.{3})(\\1)(\\1)(.{2})\\b", cpf, 
    proto = list(n1 = character(), n2 = character(), n3 = character(), n4 = character()))
```

In this case, the first capture group `123` repeats twice.

Comment: An error message appeared:: `Error in strcapture("\\b(.{3})\\1\\1.{2}\\b", cpf, proto = list(n1 = character(),  : 
  The number of captures in 'pattern' != 'length(proto)'`

Comment: But I understand how backreference works.

Comment: @neves I removed the second capture group because I thought (apparently wrongly) that it wasn't necessary.  Try restoring it and see if that fixes the error.

Comment: The error remains. :(

Comment: OK, I think this API wants 4 capture groups to match the four list items.  Try using 4 capture groups.